# Creating UIElements outside Ui thread, Silverlight

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, c#-4.0, backgroundworker, uielement

In my silverlight 4.0 application, at one point, after user pushes a button, I have to create few  UI objects that take some time (5-10seconds). During this time UI freezes of course. I decided to put creation of those objects in a background worker so UI could at least show progress bar.

But this solution does not work. To create UI object you have to be in UI thread.
If I put creation of those object inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` than again my UI freezes. In most cases without even showing progress bar. Is there a way around this?

Can I show progress bar while silverlight creates UI objects in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this forum [post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/110392.aspx/1). It may help.

Instead of using:

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {});
```

They use:

```
System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try displaying a custom message before creating UI objects inside `BeginInvoke()`.

Example:

```
private void CreateObjects()
{
    myMsg.Text = "Loading...";
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { AddObjects() });
}
```

Once all objects are created, disable the message.

You can try the similar thing with Progress Bar also.

Comment: yes, but to display myMsg you need to access UIThread, and if objects are created on the same thread Ui wont have time to update

Comment: What I was trying to say here is instead of Progress Bar you can show a message while the update is in progress. Offcourse you need to be in the UIThread to do it. BTW, did you try this?